# friends system help?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a partly working friends system, but one of my MySQL queries only selects the whole table variable and I want it to select individual parts of the table variable.

The purpose of this is to count how many times the users name occurs in the the whole table in general. This is my query:

```
SELECT Reciver, Sender
FROM Friends
WHERE (Reciver or Sender) = '%$fullname%'
  AND accepted = 2
```

The `$fullname` is a variable with the users name in it.

In the table **Friends** I have:

```
id      Sender    Reciver   accepted 
1        bob       fred       2
1        fred      jim        1
```

This is what my table looks like and for `accepted = 2` they have accepted and `1` is they are waiting.

**Question:** Can you look at all my coding I have shown here and see if their is another way (easier way) or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is that i have like 2 friends and it displays that i have 2 friends but it only displays the receivers name not the senders name and which i need

Comment: `SELECT Reciver, Sender
FROM Friends
WHERE (Reciver or Sender) like '%$fullname%'
  AND accepted = 2`

Comment: SELECT Reciver, Sender FROM Friends WHERE Reciver like '%$fullname%' OR  Sender like '%$fullname%'  AND accepted = 2 ; Apart from using "like", have you tried running that query from the mysqladmin ? and see what is returns?

Comment: Thanks guys i think i have it

Answer (score 0):

Your where may need to be updated.  Try `WHERE (Reciver  = '%$fullname%' or Sender = '%$fullname%') AND accepted = 2`

Answer (score 0):

The following will count how often the desired user appears in the database table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
WHERE (Reciver = '%$fullname%' or Sender = '%$fullname%') 
    AND accepted = 2
```

Daniel Moniz